# How to adjust width of column to content?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a column in a datagrid which I am setting the width of the textblck with a multivalue converter. But the width of the column is not modified. I would like that the width column adjust to the content of the texblock.

The column is this:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Columna2" Binding="{Binding}" Width="AUTO">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MiMultiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="UseConverterIsChecked" Source="{StaticResource vm}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="WidthColumn2" Source="{StaticResource vm}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I know that the textblock is resize correctly because I set a background to see which is the real size of the textblock.

This is the original size:

[image]

And this is when the converter set the value of the textblock:

[image]

How could I adjust the size of the column?

Thanks.

EDIT:

If I use horizontal stretch as is advised in some comment, I get this result:

[image]

EDIT:

This is the code MiMultiValueConverter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool miBlUsarConverter = (bool)values[0];
    double miDbAncho = (double)values[1];

    return (miBlUsarConverter) ? miDbAncho : 200;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `Width` of the `TextBlock` of you want to adjust the width of the column? It makes no sense. Why don't you set the width of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the width of the elements contained inside the DataGrid column, instead of the actual column. The proper way of resizing your column would be to set the width property of the DataGridTextColumn itself:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Columna2" Binding="{Binding}" Width="1*">
```

In your case, you'll want to replace it with your binding from above.

For more information, here is the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/sizing-options-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: I have tried horizontal alignement as stretch, but the result is not the expected. I have add the result in the original post.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. What your converter does is resize the elements contained in the column, instead of the column itself. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have added the code of the converter.

Comment: I have tried with width="1*" in the DataGridTextColumn but it doesn't work, when I resize to a lowwer width than the actual width of the column, the column is not resize.

Comment: you're supposed to replace 1* with your binding

Comment: My biding would be a multivalue converter, but in the Width property of the DataGridTextColumn I only can use a value converter, but I need a MultiValueConverter.